# RTC Week day byte

Tags: assembly, x86, real-time-clock

I am directly reading/writing the RTC through the port 0x70 and 0x71. As per the manual the weekday byte will hold the day of the week with Sunday=1 and values range from 1 to 7. When I read the byte I get today 4, that is Wednesday. Whereas when i read the RTC information with `hwclock -r` the day is Thursday, which is correct.

Setting the date using `hwclock` to other date and reading it with my code doesn't reflect the change in the weekday byte.

This problem persists in all systems. What can be the problem?

Comment: @Mahmoud Al-Qudsi Thanks for the retag, indeed not a C question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/CMOS) (emphasis added):

> The RTC chip is able to keep track of the current day of the week. All
>   it does is increment its "Weekday" register at midnight and reset it
>   to zero if it reaches 7. Unfortunately there is no guarantee that this
>   register was ever set correctly by anything (including when the user
>   changes the time and date using the BIOS configuration screen). **It is
>   entirely unreliable and should not be used.**
>
> The correct way to determine the current day of the week is to calculate it from the date.

I believe this answers both your original question and why changing the RTC date manually with `hwclock` does not show changes to the weekday offset (`0x07`). If it's simply a roll-over counter at midnight, that explains a lot.

As for calculating the day of the week from the date while not using system time functions such as `strptime`, have a look at this StackOverflow thread: [C Program to find day of week given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054016/c-program-to-find-day-of-week-given-date?rq=1)