# Why doesn't strptime() set tm_wday properly in this example?

Tags: c, gcc, time, clang, strptime

I'm using `strptime(3)` to parse a string representing a date:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  struct tm t;
  strptime("2015-04-19 12:00:00", "%F %T", &t); /* Sunday */
  printf("%d\n", t.tm_wday); /* Should print 0 */
  return 0;
}
```

That date is a Sunday, according to the output of `cal -y 2015`. But when I compile this on OSX (presumably with clang) it prints `6`:

```
$ gcc timetest.c ; ./a.out
6
```

whereas on Debian it prints the (correct) `0`:

```
$ gcc timetest.c ; ./a.out
0
```

Any explanation for the difference?

**UPDATE**

Here is the same program, except that `t` is initialised with a valid time and I'm reporting the return value of `strptime()`:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  time_t epoch = 0;
  struct tm t;
  char *ret;
  t = *localtime(&epoch);
  ret = strptime("2015-04-19 12:00:00", "%F %T", &t); /* Sunday */
  printf("%d\n", t.tm_wday); /* Should print 0 */
  printf("strptime() returned %p (%d)\n", ret, *ret);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ gcc timetest.c ; ./a.out
6
strptime() returned 0x10c72af83 (0)
```

Here is the `clang` version I use:

```
$ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: What's the return value of strptime() on OSX? What happens when you initialize `t` with a valid date before calling strptime()?

Comment: I've updated the program according to @Jens's suggestion.

Comment: It gives 0 for me on OS X.  `clang-700.1.81`

Comment: Taking your code verbatim and running on macOS Sierra 10.12.1 (using either GCC 6.2.0 or Clang from XCode 8.0), I get the result 6.  I added two lines: `time_t rt = mktime(&t);` after the call to `strptime()` and `printf("%lld\n", (long long)rt);` and the result changed to 0.  Now, for that, I have no explanation!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right, I can confirm that following the call to `strptime()` with a call to `mktime()` is a usable workaround for me. But I am at a loss to explain the observed behaviour.

Comment: Use `struct tm t = {0};
      tm.tm_isdst = -1;` _before_ using `&t` in later code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is simply that, by design, [the `strptime` function only sets the fields that appear in the format](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html).  Essentially, `strptime(3)` just parses fields from a given string using a supplied format into a referenced structure and performs no other computation or logic.  Since your code uses the format `%F %T` then only the fields corresponding to `%Y-%m-%d` and `%H:%M:%S` (namely `tm_{year,mon,mday,hour,min,sec}`) are modified.

You can experiment by explicitly setting `t.tm_wday` to some known value that shouldn't by set by `strptime` (e.g. 123) and verify that it is not changed by that call.  Note that you should probably initialize your `struct tm` before playing with it since any of those fields may contain random values, e.g. `struct tm t; memset((void *) &t, 0, sizeof(t));`.

Moreover, this [Linux `strptime(3)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) contains the following note which leads me to believe that the special behavior it describes is non-standard (though obviously desirable):

> The glibc implementation does not touch those fields which are not explicitly specified, except that it recomputes the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` field if any of the year, month, or day elements changed.

[This answer shows how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6054071/244128) you can use the trio of `strptime/mktime/localtime` (or `gmtime`) to populate the `tm.tm_wday` field for dates after the UNIX epoch.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the observation in the comments, here's a program derived from your code which illustrates, even if it does not explain, what is going on:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void dump_struct_tm(const char *tag, const struct tm *t)
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    printf("  Time: %.2d:%.2d:%.2d  ", t-> tm_hour, t->tm_min, t->tm_sec);
    printf("  Date: %.4d-%.2d-%.2d\n", t->tm_year + 1900, t->tm_mon + 1, t->tm_mday);
    printf("  Wday: %d Yday: %.3d (DST %d Zone [%s] offset %ld)\n", 
           t->tm_wday, t->tm_yday, t->tm_isdst, t->tm_zone, t-> tm_gmtoff);
}

int main(void)
{
    time_t epoch = 0;
    struct tm t;
    char *ret;
    t = *localtime(&epoch);
    dump_struct_tm("Epoch", &t);
    putchar('\n');

    ret = strptime("2015-04-19 12:00:00", "%F %T", &t);
    dump_struct_tm("strptime()", &t);
    time_t rt = mktime(&t);
    dump_struct_tm("mktime()", &t);
    printf("Weekday: %d\n", t.tm_wday);
    printf("strptime() returned %p (%d)\n", ret, *ret);
    printf("Unix time: %lld\n\n", (long long)rt);

    t.tm_isdst = -1;
    ret = strptime("2015-04-19 12:00:00", "%F %T", &t);
    dump_struct_tm("strptime()", &t);
    rt = mktime(&t);
    dump_struct_tm("mktime()", &t);
    printf("Weekday: %d\n", t.tm_wday);
    printf("strptime() returned %p (%d)\n", ret, *ret);
    printf("Unix time: %lld\n\n", (long long)rt);

    return 0;
}
```

This analyzes the `struct tm` (as defined by the manual page on macOS Sierra) at different points.  Note how the setting of `tm_isdst` alters the behaviour.

```
Epoch:
  Time: 16:00:00    Date: 1969-12-31
  Wday: 3 Yday: 364 (DST 0 Zone [PST] offset -28800)

strptime():
  Time: 12:00:00    Date: 2015-04-19
  Wday: 6 Yday: 108 (DST 0 Zone [(null)] offset -28800)
mktime():
  Time: 13:00:00    Date: 2015-04-19
  Wday: 0 Yday: 108 (DST 1 Zone [PDT] offset -25200)
Weekday: 0
strptime() returned 0x100c82f0c (0)
Unix time: 1429473600

strptime():
  Time: 12:00:00    Date: 2015-04-19
  Wday: 6 Yday: 108 (DST -1 Zone [(null)] offset -25200)
mktime():
  Time: 12:00:00    Date: 2015-04-19
  Wday: 0 Yday: 108 (DST 1 Zone [PDT] offset -25200)
Weekday: 0
strptime() returned 0x100c82f0c (0)
Unix time: 1429470000
```

I'm still not clear why `strptime()` mispopulates the `tm_wday` field, especially since it seems to get the `tm_yday` field correct.  The 19th of April is day 108 of the year when the 1st of January is day 0.